# AWS lambda C++ runtime in SAM

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Does anyone have a step-by-step tutorial on using SAM to package an AWS lambda function using the C++ runtime so I can run it locally? C++ is not one of the languages supported using `sam init --runtime` and I cannot work out the steps needed to package the Hello World function from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I described with a few more details. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451803/how-to-run-a-c-aws-lambda-function-locally-with-sam

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [CloudFormation package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) functionality to achieve what you're looking for.

Remember that your Lambda code must be built to binary form on `AWS Linux` because of dynamic dependencies. Lambda functions run in `AWS Linux` based containers.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I described with a few more details. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451803/how-to-run-a-c-aws-lambda-function-locally-with-sam