# How to run a C++ AWS Lambda Function locally with SAM?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, runtime, serverless-application-model

I would like to try the custom C++ runtime for AWS Lambda and testing it locally using [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html). Unfortunately I get the error `Runtime exited without providing a reason` (compare error details below). **How can I run C++ Lambda functions locally with SAM?**

**Approach:**

I am following the exact steps described in [official C++ Introduction blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/), up to the last step of "Create your C++ function". The rest of the blog is about deploying the function on Lambda (which I DO NOT want to do, since I would like to use SAM locally).

In order to use SAM, I am putting a `template.yaml` in the build dir. The structure of the `build dir` now looks like this:

```
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
|   |...
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── hello
├── hello.zip
├── Makefile
└── template.yaml

6 directories, 37 files
```

This is the content of the `template.yaml` in the build dir:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  cpp hello world

Globals: # default settings across all resources if nothing else is specified
  Function:
    Timeout: 15

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello.zip # relative location or S3 key
      Handler: hello # function to handle call? Why is this hello and not main?
      Runtime: provided
      Events:
        HelloWorld: # the name of the event
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

**Invoke:**

I am running `sam local start-api --debug` in the `debug` folder.
I am invoking the function by going to `127.0.0.1:3000/hello` in chrome.

**Error:**

Some details from the message that results from invoking the URL:

```
...
Invoking hello (provided)
Decompressing /home/path/to/folder/test_cpp_local/aws-lambda-cpp/build/hello_cpp/build/hello.zip

Fetching lambci/lambda:provided Docker container image......
Mounting /tmp/tmpm9djt4mb as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
/var/task/bin/hello: error while loading shared libraries: /var/task/lib/libc.so.6: file too short
START RequestId: 3435a342-d86d-1a59-df1a-10167070cd22 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 3435a342-d86d-1a59-df1a-10167070cd22
REPORT RequestId: 3435a342-d86d-1a59-df1a-10167070cd22  Init Duration: 29.71 ms Duration: 0.00 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 6 MB   
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 3435a342-d86d-1a59-df1a-10167070cd22 Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason"
}
Function returned an invalid response (must include one of: body, headers, multiValueHeaders or statusCode in the response object
...
```

**My System:**

I am building on a Ubuntu 16.04 using cmake 3.5.1, g++ 4.5.0, gcc 4.5.0

**Ideas how to solve this:**

I somehow have to build remote on a machine that uses AWS Linux (I hope that this is not the case)

I could use the [CloudFormationPackage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) as recommended here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699866/aws-lambda-c-runtime-in-sam). I would like to avoid this, since I would like to test locally only.

Comment: Are you sure about the `Handler` value? Did you closely follow point 2 from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/ If followed this tutorial and the result works, it should behave the same way in your local SAM environment.

Comment: Also, you can build on AWS Linux in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Run inside a docker container**

I assume that this is an issue with SAM. I was able to this just the way I build it using [docker-lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda). For this I had to extract `hello.zip` and than call it with

```
docker run --rm -v "<path/to/hello>":/var/task lambci/lambda:provided handler
```

Using this workaround I did not need to build statically.

**Build inside a docker container**

You can also build inside an amazonlinux container. A `hello_world` Dockerfile would look like this (includes the program itself):

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

RUN yum -y install make 
RUN yum -y install git 
RUN yum -y install gcc-c++
RUN yum -y install nano 
RUN yum -y install zip 
RUN yum -y install clang 
RUN yum -y install gcc-c++
RUN yum -y install libcurl-devel 
RUN yum -y install cmake3
RUN export CC=gcc && \
    export CXX=g++ && \
    cd ~  && \
    git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp.git && \
    cd aws-lambda-cpp && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake3 .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/out && \
    make &&\
    make install && \
    mkdir hello-cpp-world && \
    cd hello-cpp-world && \
    echo -e "// main.cpp\n#include <aws/lambda-runtime/runtime.h>\nusing namespace aws::lambda_runtime;\ninvocation_response my_handler(invocation_request const& request)\n{\n   return invocation_response::success(\"Hello, World!\", \"application/json\");\n}\n\nint main()\n{\nrun_handler(my_handler);\n   return 0; \n}" >> main.cpp && \
    echo -e "cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)\nset(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)\nproject(hello LANGUAGES CXX)\nfind_package(aws-lambda-runtime REQUIRED)\nadd_executable(hello \"main.cpp\")\ntarget_link_libraries(hello PUBLIC AWS::aws-lambda-runtime)\naws_lambda_package_target(hello NO_LIBC)" >> CMakeLists.txt && \
    mkdir build &&\
    cd build &&\
    cmake3 .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/out && \
    make && \
    make aws-lambda-package-hello
RUN cd / && \
    cp /root/aws-lambda-cpp/build/hello-cpp-world/build/hello.zip /artifacts/hello.zip
```

Important is, that if you are building in an amazonlinux environment, you have to include `aws_lambda_package_target(hello NO_LIBC)` to your `CMakeLists.txt`. This is in order to not include the C runtime as a dependency.

In the example I mounted a folder called `artifacts` inside my container, to which I am copying the resulting zip file.

Comment: If only the AWS docs were this clear! Thanks for this, running the Zip within Docker was exactly what I needed. Also added `-e DOCKER_LAMBDA_STAY_OPEN=1 -p 9001:9001` to be able to hit `curl http://localhost:9001/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations --data @payload.json` for interactive testing. Much easier than SAM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely here:
`/var/task/bin/hello: error while loading shared libraries: /var/task/lib/libc.so.6: file too short`

Your binary does not even invoke.

You should be able to resolve this problem by building the binary on matching version of `AWS Linux` or by building a static binary.

Comment: I clarified the answer. I'd try building a static binary since that's simplest.

Comment: Okay, so I do have to use a machine using `AWS Linux`. This seems to be a bit annoying to me. I go the impression from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdIa9vTlg9Q that this was not necessary :(

Comment: Or you can building inside a AWS Linux container, but I don't know the details of that approach :)

Comment: I was thinking about using Cloud9 for building it... might be the simplest.

Could you maybe also help me out with the building commands? How would https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/ change if I would want to bind the libs statically?

Comment: You need to change the CMake configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648357/compiling-a-static-executable-with-cmake

Comment: It did not work. I was not able to build everything statically. I was also building it in a docker container with amazonlinux. I was not able to run that zip file on Ubuntu, though

Comment: You shouldn't combine two systems/build environments like that.